# Microk8s ingress returning "not found" with nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have a microk8s cluster with nginx ingress and a .NET Orleans application deployed to some pods. Then I have a service which is attached to the pods I belive (I am new to Kubernetes and Microk8s so appoligies if I am wrong). I get the error: 404 not found when I try to access the ingress. There are no errors in the ingress-nginx-controller and no errors in my pods.

Here are my yaml:
Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cloud.solar.trest.se
  labels:
    orleans/serviceId: cloud.solar.trest.se
    orleans/clusterId: trest
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      orleans/serviceId: cloud.solar.trest.se
      orleans/clusterId: trest
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        orleans/serviceId: cloud.solar.trest.se
        orleans/clusterId: trest
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: main
          image: lordmax2/klevebrandsolarcontroller:cloud-latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 11111
            - containerPort: 30000
            - containerPort: 7298
          env:
            - name: ORLEANS_SERVICE_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.labels['orleans/serviceId']
            - name: ORLEANS_CLUSTER_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.labels['orleans/clusterId']
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: DOTNET_SHUTDOWNTIMEOUTSECONDS
              value: "120"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 180
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: solar-service
spec:
  selector:
    orleans/serviceId: cloud.solar.trest.se
    orleans/clusterId: trest
  ports:
    - name: port-11111
      protocol: TCP
      port: 11111
      targetPort: 11111
    - name: port-30000
      protocol: TCP
      port: 30000
      targetPort: 30000
    - name: port-80
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: port-443
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: port-7298
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7298
      targetPort: 7298
```

Ingress:

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: solar-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: cloud.solar.trest.se
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: solar-service
            port:
              number: 7298
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cloud.solar.trest.se
    secretName: cloud-certificate
```

The ingress looks like this when I do: `microk8s kubectl get ingress`

```
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS                  ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
solar-ingress   nginx   cloud.solar.trest.se   10.10.1.200   80, 443   117m
```

The service looks like this: `microk8s kubectl get svc`

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                       AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                                       2d4h
solar-service   ClusterIP   10.152.183.166   <none>        11111/TCP,30000/TCP,80/TCP,443/TCP,7298/TCP   3h14m
```

Here are my pods: `microk8s get pods`

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cloud.solar.trest.se-c97468cb-hwk4m   1/1     Running   0          9m26s   10.1.211.165   kdc-node-1   <none>           <none>
cloud.solar.trest.se-c97468cb-lsm4n   1/1     Running   0          8m21s   10.1.160.143   kdc-node-2   <none>           <none>
```

Here is the described ingress: `microk8s kubectl describe ingress solar-ingress`

```
Name:             solar-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.10.1.200
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  cloud-certificate terminates cloud.solar.trest.se
Rules:
  Host                  Path  Backends
  ----                  ----  --------
  cloud.solar.trest.se
                        /   solar-service:7298 (10.1.160.143:7298,10.1.211.165:7298)
Annotations:            <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                     From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                    ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    4m43s (x230 over 119m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    4m43s (x224 over 115m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    26s (x234 over 115m)    nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Here is `microk8s kubectl get all` in every namespace:

```
kdc@kdc-node-1:~ $ kubectl get all
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cloud.solar.trest.se-c97468cb-hwk4m   1/1     Running   0          25m
pod/cloud.solar.trest.se-c97468cb-lsm4n   1/1     Running   0          24m

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                       AGE
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                                       2d4h
service/solar-service   ClusterIP   10.152.183.166   <none>        11111/TCP,30000/TCP,80/TCP,443/TCP,7298/TCP   3h30m

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cloud.solar.trest.se   2/2     2            2           24h

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cloud.solar.trest.se-6c865fdb     0         0         0       24h
replicaset.apps/cloud.solar.trest.se-5b9bb67477   0         0         0       24h
replicaset.apps/cloud.solar.trest.se-c97468cb     2         2         2       25m
replicaset.apps/cloud.solar.trest.se-8577f49f4b   0         0         0       23h
kdc@kdc-node-1:~ $ kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS       AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-6jwj6        0/1     Completed   0              25h
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-hw8sf         0/1     Completed   1              25h
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7445ddc6c4-hw76d   1/1     Running     4 (133m ago)   25h

NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.152.183.230   <none>        443/TCP                      25h
service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.152.183.240   10.10.1.200   80:32307/TCP,443:32581/TCP   25h

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           25h

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7445ddc6c4   1         1         1       25h

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           17m        25h
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           17m        25h
kdc@kdc-node-1:~ $ kubectl get all -n metallb-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
pod/speaker-2lct7                 1/1     Running   0              147m
pod/speaker-rq2ls                 1/1     Running   1 (133m ago)   147m
pod/controller-749f8b5cbc-dq8sm   1/1     Running   0              36m

NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/webhook-service   ClusterIP   10.152.183.65   <none>        443/TCP   147m

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/speaker   2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   147m

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/controller   1/1     1            1           147m

NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/controller-749f8b5cbc   1         1         1       36m
replicaset.apps/controller-5f7bb57799   0         0         0       147m
kdc@kdc-node-1:~ $ kubectl get ing
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS                  ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
solar-ingress   nginx   cloud.solar.trest.se   127.0.0.1   80, 443   136m
```

*EDIT
I added metallb with an IPAddressPool and a L2Assignement to get some real ip addresses, but doesnt seem to work. If I do `microk8s kubectl port-forward svc/solar-service 7298` I am able to reach service from the master node with https://127.0.0.1:7298, but not with https://10.10.0.150:7298 which is the node ip address..

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get pods`

Comment: I have updated the post! Added metallb to try to get some real ip addresses, but doesnt seem to work, also added the uncensored version of all the configs to make it easier.. What am I missing :) @Hackerman

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, saw this log in the controller:

```
2023/12/16 09:55:12 [error] 30#30: *810462 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 94.191.136.17, server: cloud.solar.trest.se, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.1.211.165:7298/favicon.ico", host: "cloud.solar.trest.se", referrer: "https://cloud.solar.trest.se/"
```

And my backend service is https only, so added this annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`